# change data on chart by selecting the year in dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, angular, highcharts

i am displaying a chart in an angular app. I have two dropdowns to select starting year and ending year and i need my chart do display values based on the years picked. The X axis is composed by 18 cities, and the Y axis is the range "IAP" values. My data set is composed by "imob" and "rend" values, i.e. to calculate my "IAP" values for each city i need to do this operation:

IAP of city x from year 1 to year 2 = (imob.endingyear/imob.startingyear)/(rend.endingyear/rend.startingyear)

For example, when i select the starting year 2013 and the ending year 2018, the chart has to display the IAP values of each city in that interval of time. I hope my explanation is not too much confusing.

So far i have my dropdown in iapchart.controller.html file and it looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="YearpickerController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="singleSelect"> Ano Início: </label><br>
    <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect">
      <option value="option-1i">2011</option>
      <option value="option-2i">2012</option>
      <option value="option-3i">2013</option>
      <option value="option-4i">2014</option>
      <option value="option-5i">2015</option>
      <option value="option-6i">2016</option>
      <option value="option-7i">2017</option>
      <option value="option-8i">2018</option>
      <option value="option-9i">2019</option>
      <option value="option-10i">2020</option>
    </select><br>
  </form>
</div>

<div ng-controller="YearpickerController">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="singleSelect"> Ano Fim: </label><br>
    <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect">
      <option value="option-1f">2011</option>
      <option value="option-2f">2012</option>
      <option value="option-3f">2013</option>
      <option value="option-4f">2014</option>
      <option value="option-5f">2015</option>
      <option value="option-6f">2016</option>
      <option value="option-7f">2017</option>
      <option value="option-8f">2018</option>
      <option value="option-9f">2019</option>
      <option value="option-10f">2020</option>
    </select><br>
  </form>
</div>
```

To build my chart i have used Highcharts and so far its looking like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB7CW.png)

But the dropdowns are not working, i need some sort of event listener right? I am new to angular js and i dont know how to go from here.

My code in iapchart.component.ts is looking like this so far:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-widget-iapchart',
  templateUrl: './iapchart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./iapchart.component.scss']
})
export class IAPchartComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  title = 'app';
  imobsListSubs: Subscription;
  imobsList: Imob[];

  chartOptions;

  Highcharts = Highcharts;

  constructor(private imobsApi: ImobsApiService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void{

    this.imobsListSubs = this.imobsApi
      .getImobs()
      .subscribe(res => {
          this.imobsList = res;
        },
        console.error
      );

    this.chartOptions = {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Índice Valorização'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        labels: {
            rotation: -45,
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Valorização'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: 'Valor IAP: <b>{point.y:.1f} </b>'
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
    },
    exporting: {
      enabled: true,
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Valor IAP',
        data: [
            ['Aveiro', 1.2],
            ['Beja', 0.8],
            ['Braga', 1.2],
            ['Bragança', 1.7],
            ['Castelo Branco', 1.1],
            ['Coimbra', 0.7],
            ['Évora', 1.4],
            ['Faro', 1.2],
            ['Guarda', 1.0],
            ['Leiria', 0.7],
            ['Lisboa', 1.5],
            ['Portalegre', 1.2],
            ['Porto', 1.4],
            ['Santarém', 1.2],
            ['Setúbal', 0.6],
            ['Viana do Castelo', 0.9],
            ['Vila Real', 1.3],
            ['Viseu', 0.8]
        ],
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            rotation: 0,
            color: '#000000',
            align: 'right',
            format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
            y: -20, // 10 pixels down from the top
            style: {
                fontSize: '13px',
                fontFamily: 'Times New Roman, sans-serif'
            }
        }
    }]
    };

    HC_exporting(Highcharts);

    setTimeout(() =>{
      window.dispatchEvent(
        new Event('resize')
      );
    }, 300);
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.imobsListSubs.unsubscribe();
  }
```

The data I provided there is only an example of IAP values, i also need to know how to write my dataset there without making the code very big...

Answer (score 0):

The functionality that you are looking for is already built into the Highcharts stock, the only difference is that instead of the dropdown list you can use the range selector input to manipulate the axis range. Range selectors are using the `axis.setExtremes()` method under the hood, so to make it work you would need to call the `axis.setExtremes()` method with ranges given in the ms.

**API references:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

**Live demo:** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-basic-line-brzswa?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Actually, this is not it. Like i said, i need to change the year range of the data, but my Y axis is IAP values and my X axis is city names, and those are not changeable. The dropdown choices will only affect the IAP values, based on which years are picked.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you correctly. If you want to setExtremes (range) just for the yAxis instead of the xAxis all you have to do is to call that method on the yAxis. Simplified demo (vanilla js): https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9tL8vue3/

Comment: I dont want to set extremes, the y and x axis wont change! Only the years will change in the dropdown will change, which will change the IAP values i.e., its like a different data set everytime i pick different years

Comment: If you want to set new data you could jest override the chartOptions and set the update flag to true. Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update

Comment: but how can i link my options on the dropdown to select years to the chart data? maybe an event listener of some sort?

Comment: Yes, you could use the `(change)` event to access the selected data and then use it to apply update. Simplified example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update-q3oquj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: This only changes the title.. maybe i am not being clear with this. when i pick the years options in the dropdown, the values of IAP of each city will change, for example, the IAP of Viseu will go from 1.5 to 1.8

Comment: That's just an example, there is not much difference in updating the title or data. I updated my demo now you can update the chart's data basing on the selected value. Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-optimal-way-to-update-q3oquj?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: thank you so much man, ill try to update my code. and sorry or taking some time to explain my problem